# What does "Coherent" mean in coherent spectroscopy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, spectroscopy, coherent-states

I find this on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopy): "Coherent or resonance spectroscopy are techniques where the radiative energy couples two quantum states of the material in a coherent interaction that is sustained by the radiating field. " It gives some insigts but can anyone give a more detailed argument? Thanks!

Comment: Really annoying that there's a link on the same wikipedia page for "coherent spectroscopy" that takes you back to the original page... I always imagine coherent processes as making the light quanta (photons) have the exact correct energy to make an electron jump one energy level. Then the light can excite the electron (or nucleus in NMR), the electron can de-excite and re-emit back into the same wavelength range, and you can inspect the re-emitted light for phase changes etc by interfering it with the incident light

Comment: The R P Photonics Encyclopedia is a good place to start. Try the article on [Coherence](https://www.rp-photonics.com/coherence.html). Perhaps you are looking for [Coherent States](https://www.rp-photonics.com/coherent_states.html)?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic yes I kind of agree with you. My current understanding is that light can excite coherent state of atoms/molecules.

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks but when we talk about spectroscopy we always talk about matters. The links you sent are all discussing light itself.

Comment: So I'm thinking along the lines of [Ramsey interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_interferometry) where changing the frequency of the incident light (which must be coherent in the sense of @mmesser314) lets you scan the detuning parameter and thereby extract information about the energy levels in the matter system. Ramsey interferometry is with nuclear energy levels but the same principles will apply for electronic levels too